# Is there any way to get notifications for all apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, notifications

Is there any way to receive all local/remote notifications iOS device gets from inside my app.
I know that this is a security matter and probably there is no way to do that. But I want to be sure.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**

You can't get any handler or callback after receiving notifications for another apps. iOS will not allow you to do same. You can just receive and handle notifications for your app only.

While you can do this in android as android OS allows you to listen actions and events occurred in other apps as well.